# Reactive UI Extending View Support The Type has a on_PropertyName_Changed method ** which is static

Tags: xamarin.forms, plugins, reactiveui, fody, freshmvvm

Based off this link: https://reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/view-location/extending-iviewfor

Whenever I try to execute the code in the example using the RG.Plugins.Popup nuget I receive the following error: `Fody: The Type MyType '1 has a on_PropertyName_Changed method (OnViewModelChanged) which is static`.

My Code is exactly like the links code. Not sure why its causing this error to occur.

.... UPDATE....

Damn, So if anyone runs into this issue... my solution was removing the following weaver from the fodyweavers.xml file

```
<PropertyChanged/>   --- REmove this line if added solves the problem!?
```

Why is this? Why does removing the above line solve the issue?
Below is my FodyWeaver file

```
 <Weavers xmlns:"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="FodyWeavers.xsd">
          <PropertyChanged/>
          <ReactiveUI/>
 </Weavers>
```

Comment: The ReactiveObject derived classes aren't compatible with the PropertyChanged fody. You can add a `DoNotNotify` attribute above those classes, or you can use filters to avoid generating for specific namespaces. See https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged#notes for further details.

Comment: Thanks @GlennWatson after reading the notes DoNotNotify is exactly what I need in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

I was just going to say.  The code in the example is working because I use it.  Your error points to ReactiveUI.Fody being the problem.

Can you provide a reproduction of what you had that was different from the sample?

Comment: Check Updated post